# Highcharter Sankey

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I am trying to create a sankey diagram using the following data frame and code:

```
UKvisits <- data.frame(origin=as.character(c(
  "France", "Germany", "USA",
  "Irish Republic", "Netherlands",
  "Spain", "Italy", "Poland",
  "Belgium", "Australia", 
  "Other countries", rep("UK", 5))),
 visit=as.character(c(
   rep("UK", 11), "Scotland",
  "Wales", "Northern Ireland", 
  "England", "London")),
 weights=c(
  c(12,10,9,8,6,6,5,4,4,3,33)/100*31.8, 
  c(2.2,0.9,0.4,12.8,15.5)))
```

Highcharter line:

```
hchart(UKvisits, "sankey", hcaes(from = origin, to = visit, weight = weights))
```

This example has been copied from here: https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/blob/master/dev/highcharts-v6.R

For some reason whenever I run this, the plot screen remains white and nothing is being plotted.

I am trying this on R Studio version 1.1.423 (R Version: 4.3)

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Doesnt seem to be an RStudio issue, even when using the R console it doesn't seem to plot anything. However, I would change the second code block from `hchart(data, ...)` to `hchart(UKvisits)`, because that's what your data frame is named

Comment: I've found the `highcharter` library to be difficult to work with outside of the core functionality that has been implemented via the `hchart` function. While it probably is possible to dig into the `highcharter` documentation, and figure out how to make this sankey work in R, you might be better off using another library, or writing the code in Javascript, since you can directly reference the Highcharts documentation

Comment: Sorry there was a typo when I've wrote the ```hchart(data, ...)``` 
The problem is still persistent @onlyphantom

@Mako212 I have tried using the highcharter function and that has the same result.

Comment: Maybe consider the `networkD3` library? It seems like there's better documentation on how to create a sankey: https://christophergandrud.github.io/networkD3/#sankey

Comment: @Mako212 you're right. I think the best choice for me at the moment is using googlevis package -> https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/vignettes/googleVis_examples.html

Comment: I copied your code and it worked perfectly with me.

Comment: @FerandDalatieh interesting. Mine still doesn't work. It displays just an empty page without any graphs. Any change you can tell me your R studio and R version. Thank you

Comment: @GabrielOana I have R version 3.4.4; RStudio version 1.1.383 and the package highcharter version 0.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same issue. First I got the javascript console error:

```
a is undefined
```

I wasn't using the correct function highchartOutput() in ui.R, then I got this in the javascript console:

```
Highcharts Error #17 The requested series type does not exist...
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50242318/highcharts-sankey-diagram-in-r) and a comment suggested installing the dev version of highcharter via:

```
devtools::install_github("jbkunst/highcharter")
```

And that fixed the issue for me, using the simple code from that post:

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = 'sankey') %>%
  hc_add_series(
      data = list(
        list(from = 'AT', to = 'DE', weight = 10),
        list(from = 'DE', to = 'CH', weight = 5),
        list(from = 'DE', to = 'FI', weight = 5))
      )
```

And I was able to work from there. Seems like you must use the dev version if you want to do a Sankey chart.

Comment: That worked indeed. There were some issues where I had to reinstall some packages but it worked perfectly. Thank you for bringing this up :)