# HighCharts Sankey Diagram in R

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I'd like to create a sankey diagram using the highcharter library in R. Usually I'm just able to look at the javascript code for the plot and translate it for R, but for sankey plots I'm having some trouble. I'd like to just start by creating something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/z2rL672w/3/

Here's my attempt so far. I'm having trouble where to place the "keys" argument.

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type='sankey') %>%
  hc_add_series_list(
    list(
      keys=c('from', 'to', 'weight')
    ),
    list(
      data=list(
        list(
          from='AT',
          to='DE',
          weight=10
        ),
        list(
          from='DE',
          to='CH',
          weight=5
        ),
        list(
          from='DE',
          to='FI',
          weight=5
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

EDIT:

I'm now trying the following. Still having a bit of trouble

```
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

dat <- data.frame(from=c('AT', 'DE', 'CH', 'DE'),
                   to=c('DE', 'CH', 'DE', 'FI'),
                   weight=c(10, 5, 15, 5)) %>%
  toJSON()

highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type='sankey') %>%
  hc_series(dat)
```

Comment: You don't need `keys` property if your points are defined as JSONs (e.g. `{from: 'AT' to: 'DE', weight: 10}`): http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/28r99qbj/   Practical usage of `keys` property is explained in the **API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sankey.keys

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'm still having a little trouble though. Can you check my attempt above?

Comment: I don't know much about R, so I don't know what exactly is going on in your code. Here's a list of supported data formats in Highcharts: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series Maybe it'll help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the function `hc_add_series` (without keys) and it worked:

#### for the fisrt attempt:

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = 'sankey') %>%
  hc_add_series(
      data = list(
        list(from = 'AT', to = 'DE', weight = 10),
        list(from = 'DE', to = 'CH', weight = 5),
        list(from = 'DE', to = 'FI', weight = 5))
      )
```

[image]

#### for the second attempt:

```
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

dat <- data.frame(from = c('AT', 'DE', 'CH', 'DE'),
                  to = c('DE', 'CH', 'DE', 'FI'),
                  weight = c(10, 5, 15, 5)) %>%
  toJSON()

highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = 'sankey') %>%
  hc_add_series(data = dat)
```

[image]

I hope that could help :)

#### edited note:

I use a development version 0.6.0 of highcharter, to install it please use: `devtools::install_github("jbkunst/highcharter")`

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm not getting any errors but not getting any display either :( what version of highcharter are you using?

Comment: I have highcharter(0.6.0).

Comment: I'm interested in this too. How did you get v0,6? It looks like the current version is 0.5 (https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=highcharter)

Comment: It looks like this is a developmental feature. @JoeBringley try downloading the developmental version.

Comment: Oh ya it is a development version, and you can install it using:

devtools::install_github("jbkunst/highcharter")